# translation/localization workflow for nodejs/express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, internationalization, express, redis

What setup do you use for localization in your nodejs/express app?

Right now I'm using [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) in my project. But I'm not happy with the storage in the json files. I'd like to have the translations stored in a database.

I found a promising module named [dialect](https://github.com/masylum/dialect). It can store the translations in mongodb and there's also a module from the same author which enables you to manage the translations via a webinterface([dialect-http](https://github.com/masylum/dialect-http)).

Unfortunately the dialect module doesn't seem to work with latest stable versions of node. The problem is known for 2 months but since nothing was updated since then I guess the module isn't actively maintained anymore.

I think using a redis db for storing the translations would also make sense. I don't know if there's an module for that.

Maybe you guys have some hints or know of any good modules?

Comment: Just curious - what are your reasons for preferring i18n resources in a database over flat files? Personally I'd go with the latter.

Comment: i like the solution that dialect offers, where you have a web interface to manage the translations that are stored in the db. but i guess you are right, if i had the translations in flat files and had a web interface that would read/write the files so that translation collaboration is made easy it would be just as good.

Comment: Maybe you shoyld try this article: http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=647

Comment: I also preferred to keep translations in the database to prevent write file permission. However till the day that I setup a mongo web application with a database for each user. In that case it makes sense to keep the translations with the code, so I used json file storage for the translations.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just fork [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) and overwrite the *read* and *write* functions with your own persistence mechanism?

https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/blob/master/i18n.js#L235

It seems like you could easily persist the json data within a redis key instead of a json file with a few changes.

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you to use lingua. Here an example =) http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=647

Answer (score 2):

Another option to lingua might be http://i18next.com/node comes with backends in redis, mongodb or couchDb (and Filesystem of course!)